# Creating Custom Syntax Errors rather than using Run Timer Errors / Exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to do validate an equation before compiling my code and prevent it from compiling successfully. So still within the editor. here is an example of what I want to do:

```
public static Matrix operator + (Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        if (A.length != B.length || A.width != B.width)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Matrix A must be the same size as matrix B");

        // Do things
    }
```

if I write `C = A + B;` and compile it will throw an exception. I want rather it do the validation before compiling and show an error message in the Console.

Comment: How compiler knows about `A.length` and `B.length`? They are variables. They changes.

Comment: Cant be done in any stock standard way, or any other way i can think of for that matter

Comment: I think you are using wrong tech terms here. Before Compilation all you have is the Source Code (plain text C# code files + xml + other stuff). After compilation You have Binaries/Assemblies - (Still no State/Data). The Data/State is created only after your program runs and the expected code flow happens. Now, coming to your case - No the InvalidOperationException will not b thrown when you COMPILE after writing C = A + B; Why?? because Neither A nor B (State/Data) has been initialized yet. They get created when your Code executes and the initilization/assigments happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve what you want. Suppose you allow the user to enter a Matrix with arbitrary dimensions. Then the compiler already has done its work and can't know about the dimensions the user choose. So the compiler can't validate, if two matrices have compatible dimensions. You may can write an analyzer that performs some static code analysis and reports dimension mismatches, but it wont find all, and i doubt that's worth the effort to write one.

The only way to enforce the behavior by the compiler is to create a distinct type for each dimension. But i strongly recommend you not to do this.